# Being closed under conjunction and satisfiability

Tags: logic, model-theory, first-order-logic

Suppose $M \models T$, $A \subseteq M$, and $f:A \to M$ is partial elementary. Let $b\in M-A$. Let
$$
\Gamma= \big\{\phi(v,f( \bar{a}  ): \bar{a}  \in A^m  \wedge  M\models\phi(b, \bar{a}  )\big\} 
$$

If $\phi(v,f( \bar{a} ) )\in \Gamma $, then $M\models\exists v \phi(v, \bar{a}  ) $ and hence, because $f$ is partial elementary, $M\models\exists v \phi(v, f(\bar{a} ) ) $. Thus, because $\Gamma$ is closed under conjunctions, $\Gamma$ is satisfiable.

Could you please explain why **$\Gamma$ is satisfiable**!

Comment: Hint: Compactness!

Comment: I know we should use compactness. we know $\Gamma$ contains conjunction of finite elements of it. So why it has a model then?

Comment: If $\Gamma$ is closed under finite conjunctions, then you only need to consider single formulas. So you really just need to see that if $\phi(v, f(\bar{a})) \in \Gamma$, then $\mathcal{M} \models \exists v \phi(v, f(\bar{a}))$. Do you see why this must be the case (using the fact that $f$ is partial elementary)?

Comment: I see why that's true. But if $M\models \exists v \phi(v,f(\bar{a}))$ is it true that $M$ is a model for $\Gamma$? I think it must be the case that $M\models \forall v \phi(v,f(\bar{a}))$ so that $M$ is a model for it and thus satisfiable. Am I right?

Comment: $\Gamma$ is a set of formulas with the free variable $v$.  So usually $\Gamma$ being satisfiable means that $\Gamma$ being satisfiable as a theory in the signature $\tau \cup \{v\}$, where $\tau$ is the original signature of $M$, and $v$ is regarded as a constant symbol.  This is a situation similar to having an existential quantifier for $v$ in the original language.

Comment: @Aref "If $M \models \exists v \phi(v, f(\bar{a})$ is it reu taht $M$ is a model for $\Gamma$?" No, but you should be trying to prove $\Gamma$ is satisfiable using the compactness theorem. That means, $\Gamma$ is satisfiable if every finite subset of $\Gamma$ is satisfiable.